# Show alter after messages will be received from post requests

Tags: python, flask

My current problem is that I want to display an alert on my flask website which should be shown after I post a request to the flask server.

I tried already with some fetch in my javascript. But I don't have any clue how to get it to work.

```
fetch('_get_message')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    alert(data);
    console.log(data); // Prints result from `response.json()` in getRequest
})
.catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Flask server:

```
@app.route("/_get_message", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def get_message():
    if request.method == "POST":
        received_data = request.data.decode()
        # check received json data
        if received_data == None:
            return "No data found in post", 400
        print(received_data)
        to_display = {"message": received_data}
        return jsonify(to_display)
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return jsonify(to_display)
    else:
        return "Method not allowed", 305
```

Comment: don't you get error message when you run in console/terminal/cmd.exe ?

Comment: first: try to load page `/_get_message` without JavaScript. Second: use JavaScript's console in browser to see if there is no errors in JavaScript. Third: in JavaScipr try `/_get_message` with `/` - it can make difference when page has url `/folder/page`